# Unable to autoload constant, expecting FILEPATH to define it - in other words, huh?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, constants, autoload

When I try to access my localhost, I get the following message.

**LoadError in ListingsController#index

Unable to autoload constant Listing, expected C:/Sites/redemo/app/models/listing.rb to define it**

This is the code it refers to in listings_controller.rb

```
# GET /listings.json
  def index
    @listing =Listing.all
  end
```

My listing.rb is as follows:

```
 class Listings < ActiveRecord::Base
        mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
 end
```

Please, what else am I supposed to do to define it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You check your model definition. While controller is **`Listings`**, model should be **`Listing`**
Therefore change to this;

```
class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base
     mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```